# reduce pause in garbage collection

Tags: java, neo4j, garbage-collection, heap-memory, structr

I think I've got a problem with the configuration of the garbage collection.
The Server use a jetty with structr (neo4j) and after a few requests the server stands still because of the garbage collection.

My server has 8 cores and 48gb ram

I start the application with this parameters

"-server -d64 -Xms20g -Xmx20g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseNUMA -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:MaxNewSize=8g"

Could you help me to find the right configuration for the gc? 
Do you need more informations?

This shows the work of the gc and the heap of my application. (gcviewer)

- yellow - shows the young generation
- red - shows the heap size
- green - shows the gc time
- grey - shows the reserved young generation space
- purple - shows the reserved heap

[image]

Comment: First thought is to reduce the young gen, to prevent long GC's. Just for your info, maybe this article gives you some useful informations. https://engineering.linkedin.com/garbage-collection/garbage-collection-optimization-high-throughput-and-low-latency-java-applications

Comment: How many requests are prcessed in your graph (in about 20 minutes)?

Answer (score 2):

> and after a few requests the server stands still because of the garbage collection.
>
> green - shows the gc time

Your image suggests otherwise, the green line shows sub-second pauses a few minutes after startup.

Either the perceived hangs are caused by something else or you should provide the whole GC log and indicate which particular GC occurrence you consider problematic.